# In BC2, which vehicle unlocks still work in a not-driver-position?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

In Battlefield Bad Company 2, which (if any) of the vehicle unlocks are working if you are not in the driver's seat, but e.g. in the tank's gunner position or as a passenger in a helicopter?
Some are easy to test (zoom, smoke), but do increased firepower and increased armor gadgets still modify the weapon / armor?

Comment: I've also wondered about this, but I have yet to see an official statement by DICE. There's plenty of players that have tested things if you Google something like "bc2 vehicle perks not driver". You'll get forum discussions like this: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1185745

Answer (score 2):

- **Alternative Weapon Package**: if you're gunner on gunship, you have tracer darts as alternative fire
- **Improved Warheads Package**: according to specs increases damage on **all** vehicle weapons, thus should also work on gunner
- **Active Armor Upgrade**: vehicle should get upgrade if at least one player in it has the specialization. It's not cumulative (eg. you don't get 2 or more upgrades for 2 or more players with it)